# Powershell keep DataGridView selection when multiple CheckBoxes are changed

Tags: powershell, datagridview

I've been breaking my head over this problem. If I have a CheckBox Column in a `DataGridView` how can Multiple CheckBoxes be edited at the same time **and** keep the selection.

I do have the following Form working fine with editing multiple Checkboxes but the selection is lost after the cell state is changed. I do understand that my solution is rather unconventional and not as described in the Microsoft Docs (which I tried to follow but did not lead to figure this out).

Sorry for the lengthy code but it makes for a good example:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form -Property @{
    Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(232,170)
    FormBorderStyle = 'FixedDialog'
    MaximizeBox = $False
    StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
}

$DataGridView = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView -Property @{
    Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(206,113)
    Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,10)
    MultiSelect = $True
    SelectionMode = 'CellSelect'
    AutoSizeColumnsMode = 'Fill'
    AllowUserToAddRows = $False
    RowHeadersVisible = $False
    AllowUserToResizeColumns = $False
    AllowUserToResizeRows = $False
    ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = 'DisableResizing'
    ColumnHeadersVisible = $False
}

$CheckBoxColumn = New-object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn
$DataGridView.Columns.Add($CheckBoxColumn) | Out-Null
$DataGridView.ColumnCount = 1
$DataGridView.Columns[0].ReadOnly = $False

$GridData = [ordered]@{
    '0' = $True; '1' = $True; '2' = $True; '3' = $True; '4' = $True
}

for($i = 0; $i -lt 5; $i++){
    $DataGridView.Rows.Add($GridData[$i]) | Out-Null
}

$global:Selection = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$DataGridView.Add_SelectionChanged({
    if (($DataGridView.SelectedCells.RowIndex).Count -gt '1'){
        $global:Selection = $DataGridView.SelectedCells.RowIndex
    }
})

$DataGridView.Add_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged({
    for($i = 0; $i -lt $global:Selection.Count; $i++){ 
        $DataGridView.Rows[$global:Selection[$i]].Cells[0].Value = $DataGridView.Rows[$DataGridView.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value
    }
    $DataGridView.EndEdit()
    $global:Selection = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
})

$form.Controls.Add($DataGridView)
$form.ShowDialog()
```

The main part I do not understand how to work around is when the Cell State is triggered it will wipe the selection. My solution was to store the selection first and then reset it at the end of the Cell Stat change to then be able to select a single Cell again.
I am aware of `CellValueChanged` and tried it that way but I always failed because of the selection change at the Event State Change as if I'm chasing my own tail. Boggles my mind if it is possible to keep the selection.

Comment: Well, the code as posted is invalid and will error off with stuff like [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Unable to index into an object of type System.Boolean.] And agreed, what you are doing is unconventional.

Comment: @postanote i didn't get that error but i think it occurred when filling the `DataGridView` with the data. i corrected this in the code example.

Comment: Yep, I did correct that on my quick look at your code before the comment. Yet, it still is just a UX/UI with pre-selected checkboxes in the Datagrid. Are you saying, of this checklist, you are CRTL+click to select them all to do say multi-row editing while not impacting another selected row/cell?. Of course, elements must have focus before you can do anything to them, and thus any previous element(s) must lose focus and form events associated are triggered. So, this is a UX/UI ZOrder/Event flow question vs a PowerShell one, since events are form specific. So, maybe post full code to CodeReview

Comment: Well yes for us it's a coding problem however the enduser just expects things to happen in a certain way when clicking things :-) For me it is unexpected to lose the multiline selection after clicking a checkbox. Maybe the way it currently behaves is how most people would expect it. I was just wonder if it is possible.

Comment: ;-} .... Nah.. you can't do this. If you consider this same thing say, in Excel and you multi-select column the change to a cell, you loose columns. You select rows and select a column, then you loose rows.  Well, if you don't ctrl-click that. Do, the same sending stuff to OGV, same thing. Yet in your posted code, you are only showing the chkbox not other cells to be selected. So, post a gif somewhere to show what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concluding from further testing and comments, holding the selection is not possible (until proven wrong).

Any form of interacting with a Cell will change the selection state first. Therefore it is impossible to know for Powershell if a Click inside a Cell is meant as Selecting a single Cell or changing its Value (in this case a Checkbox). Both states at that very instant look exactly the same to Powershell.

Possible solution in the future could be QuantumBits.